# Convert PDF to Word/ODF

Tags: pdf, format-conversion, doc

I would like to convert a pdf to an word or ODF file.

If found several programs like Okular, but I don't know how to do that.

Edit: It is a text pdf, not an image pdf.

Comment: Is it a text-based PDF or an image-based PDF? If you open the PDF in any reader, can you use a cursor to highlight words properly? Or is it a graphical cursor that just shades boxes?

Comment: Not an Ubuntu solution but I find good sucess using these online file convertors https://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-odt/ your mileage may vary but it is worth a try.

Comment: You can use LibreOffice for this task, however it'll output the DOC text in text boxes. I'm trying to get rid of that text boxes too but didn't get any solution yet.